# understanding how to copy data

Tags: java, int, copy-constructor, copying

I am working on some homework for entry level java, and i ran in to this. I have no idea what it is having me do. Is this literally just setting "`Date`" equal to the value in `"Date d"`? or am I missing something? I don't feel like that long of an explanation would be used for a one line piece of code.

Could someone please explain what is happening here and what I am missing?

> Copy constructor: this is a constructor that accepts one parameter of
>   type Date and then sets the receiving (or executing) objects instance
>   variables equal to those of the parameter object. The result is that
>   the receiving object is a copy of the formal parameter object:

```
public Date( Date d )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is take all the fields of d and copy them over to the new Date. So if a Date has a time, a day, a month, and a year, copy all those to the new Date. That's it.

Comment: so, if i am understanding right, all I would need to do is use an accesor to pull the date, and set it to whatever it pulls?

Comment: @JWelch yes, IF the only field in a Date object is the date. If there are multiple fields, you need to use an accesor to pull each of them and set the new object appropriately for each.

Comment: @JWelch no problem, happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Complex {

private double re, im;

// A normal parametrized constructor 
public Complex(double re, double im) {
    this.re = re;
    this.im = im;
}

// copy constructor
Complex(Complex c) {
    System.out.println("Copy constructor called");
    re = c.re;
    im = c.im;
}

// Overriding the toString of Object class
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "(" + re + " + " + im + "i)";
  }
}

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Complex c1 = new Complex(10, 15);

    // Following involves a copy constructor call
    Complex c2 = new Complex(c1);   

    // Note that following doesn't involve a copy constructor call as 
    // non-primitive variables are just references.
    Complex c3 = c2;   

    System.out.println(c2); // toString() of c2 is called here
  }
}
```